# Can't access logical partition immediately

Tags: partitioning, mount, thunderbird

Bit of a newbie question: I have a logical partition called "Workspace" (I am only running one hard drive). The logical partition contains media files for use from multiple operating systems (dual boot). I have it mapped as /media/mark/Workspace and it appears in Nautilus. I can click on it to browse it. It doesn't appear to actually mount until I click on it in Nautilus. Recently I moved my Thunderbird profile to 'Workspace' and now before I can run Thunderbird, I have to open Nautilus and view that drive before Thunderbird will run (otherwise Thunderbird says "can't find profile"). So I'm assuming that for some reason the partition isn't ACTUALLY mounting until I manually access it.

Can someone please tell me how to make it mount immediately on boot?

Comment: Can you post the output of `mount` and the contents of your `fstab`?

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Actually, I found the solution. I had to automatically mount it in "Startup" which I did by following these instructions -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions